# Angular material - custom theme not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

After migration angular 14 to 15 , I found error my custom theme not working with angular material , I found error in pagination but i fixed them but now i d'ont found solution for this error

this is code style.scss:

`   @use '@angular/material' as mat;

```
@include mat.core();

$md-test-blue: (50 : #e8eafe, 100 : #c5cbfe, 200 : #9fa9fd, 300 : #7987fc, 400 : #5c6dfb, 500 : #3f53fa, 600 : #394cf9, 700 : #3142f9, 800 : #2939f8, 900 : #1b29f6, A100 : #ffffff, A200 : #f6f7ff, A400 : #c3c7ff, A700 : #aaaeff,
    contrast: (50 : #000000, 100 : #000000, 200 : #000000, 300 : #000000, 400 : #ffffff, 500 : #ffffff, 600 : #ffffff, 700 : #ffffff, 800 : #ffffff, 900 : #ffffff, A100 : #000000, A200 : #000000, A400 : #000000, A700 : #000000)
);
$md-test-red: (50 : #fde5e9, 100 : #fbbdc8, 200 : #f891a4, 300 : #f56580, 400 : #f34464, 500 : #f12349, 600 : #ef1f42, 700 : #ed1a39, 800 : #eb1531, 900 : #e70c21, A100 : #ffffff, A200 : #ffdee0, A400 : #ffabb1, A700 : #ff9199,
contrast: (50 : #000000, 100 : #000000, 200 : #000000, 300 : #000000, 400 : #ffffff, 500 : #ffffff, 600 : #ffffff, 700 : #ffffff, 800 : #ffffff, 900 : #ffffff, A100 : #000000, A200 : #000000, A400 : #000000, A700 : #000000)
);
@import "./mixins.scss";

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
html {
  font-size: 14px;
}

:root {
  --primary-color: #F12349;
  --accent-color: #3F53FA;
  --nav-color1: rgba(0,0,0,.87);
  --nav-color2: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  --white-background: #ffffff;
  --input-border-style: solid;
  --input-border-width: 1px;
  --input-border-untouched-color: #868898;
  --input-border-touched-color: #5264FA;
  --input-border-invalid-color: red;
  --input-border-radius: 4px;
  --input-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(73,86,92,0.12), 0 0 4px 0 rgba(73,86,92,0.1);

}


$test-font-family: "'sofia-pro', sans-serif";
$typography-levels: mat.define-legacy-typography-config(
  $font-family: "'sofia-pro', sans-serif",
  //$display-4: mat.define-typography-level(11px, 8px, 700)
);
$typography: mat.define-legacy-typography-config($test-font-family);
@include mat.all-component-typographies($typography);

$test-primary: mat.define-palette($md-test-blue);
$test-accent: mat.define-palette($md-test-red);
$theme: mat.define-light-theme($test-primary, $test-accent);
@include mat.all-component-themes($theme);



@import './rexmat-theme.scss';

/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
```

`

how to resolve this error in angular 15 , angular material used is 15.2.0